# What Registration Properties are needed to get Database Workbench up and running?

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I am a [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com/database_workbench/) fan from way back, but bizarrely have not used it for quite awhile.

I downloaded a trial version and am trying to "Register Server" as a first step.

The problem is I don't know what to use for which properties. I need to know:

```
Alias
Host
Instance
With "Use SQL Server Authentication" checked:
    Username
    Password
```

I've tried to guess my way through what is needed where, but nothing has worked.

I can connect to the database in (C#) code with this connection string:
    "SERVER=PlatypusSQL42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=youinnocentdog;PWD=contrasena;Connection Timeout=0";

And so I have tried these values:

```
Alias: DBWBSQLServer
Host: PlatypusSQL42
Instance: duckbilldata
Username: youinnocentdog
Password:contrasena
```

..and this:

```
Alias: PlatypusSQL42
Host: duckbilldata
Instance: 
Username: youinnocentdog
Password:contrasena
```

...but with both of them, I get, "*[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]Specified SQL server not found.*"

What values are needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance is not the database in the server you are connecting to. You can actually have more than one Sql Server running in the same operating system. You're using the default instance, so don't use that field or leave it blank.

```
Host: PlatypusSQL42
Username: youinnocentdog
Password:contrasena
```

Comment: Nothing for Alias or Instance? (Just "anything" for Alias, that is?)

Comment: Could alias just be a friendly name for the connection in your tool?

Comment: Yes, I just used "DBWBSQLServer" and it worked; thanks.